# vs2010 addin yielding control to user

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, add-in

I have created an add-in for visual studio which functionally all works well.
However, the process can take a while and i would like to yield control back to the user every once in a while.

Any ideas on how to do that ?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents(). Or move processing to a background thread.